# xy diagram problem: too wide, some arrows too short

Tags: packages, diagrams, xy-pic

I'm trying to write the diagrams of the isomorphism theorems, and I'm having problems. Some objects are too wide, and some arrows too short. Currently I have

```
$$\xymatrix{A\ar[r]^\pi\ar[d]_\rho & A/C\ar[d]_\tau\ar@{-->}[dl]_\sigma\\
                A/B\ar@{-->}[r]^\theta  & (A/C)/(B/C)\\}\hspace{-4mm}$$
$$\xymatrix{A\ar[r]^\rho\ar[d]_\iota\ar[dr]_\varphi & A/(A\cap N)\ar@{-->}[d]_\theta\\
                A\,N\ar[r]^\pi  & A\,N/N\\}$$
```

which produces

[image]

instead of

[image].

Notice that the problem is the position of (A/C)/(B/C) and A/(A\cap N): both should be positioned more to the right (left justified), so that all arrows were more or less equally long.

How can I **specify the length of arrows** and **position/justification of objects**? I'm using `\usepackage[all]{xy}`.

Comment: thanks for the points which enabled me to post the pics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\mathrlap` feature of mathtools:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all,pdf,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{A\ar[r]^\pi\ar[d]_\rho & 
            A/C\ar[d]_\tau\ar@{-->}[dl]_\sigma\\
          A/B\ar@{-->}[r]^\theta  & (A/C)\mathrlap{/(B/C)}}
\]
\[
\xymatrix{A\ar[r]^\rho\ar[d]_\iota\ar[dr]^\varphi &
            A/(A\mathrlap{{}\cap N)}\ar@{-->}[d]_\theta\\
          AN\ar[r]^\pi  & AN/N}
\]
\end{document}
```

You are lucky that the big objects are in the final column.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you :). Is there also a way to lengthen the vertical arrows, so that the diagram would have a more suare-like and less rectangle-like shape?

Comment: With `\xymatrix@R+12pt{...}` you add 12pt to the length of the vertical arrows. In order to get alignment of the entries, add `\mathstrut` to each one; if no entry is too big, this effectively gives them the same height.

Answer (score 6):

You can shift a node to the right be preceding it by `*+[r]` and then enclosing the node in braces.  Here's how your examples would look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    A\ar[r]^\pi\ar[d]_\rho
    & A/C\ar[d]_\tau\ar@{-->}[dl]_\sigma\\
    A/B\ar@{-->}[r]^\theta
    & *+[r]{(A/C)/(B/C)}
  }%\hspace{-4mm}
\end{displaymath}
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix{
    A\ar[r]^\rho\ar[d]_\iota\ar[dr]_\varphi
    & *+[r]{A/(A\cap N)} \ar@{-->}[d]_\theta\\
    A\,N\ar[r]^\pi
    & A\,N/N}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

That produces:[image]

Comment: is there a way to make the top A/C and bottom A/C in (A/C)/(B/C) aligned? Also, is there a way to lengthen the vertical arrows, so that the diagram would have a more suare-like and less rectangle-like shape?

Comment: @Leon Lampret, for the alignement try : *+[r]{A/C}

Comment: @Leon Lampret: For the alignment, as @Matsaya suggests, make that node `*+[r]{A/C}`.  To lengthen the vertical arrows, set the row spacing to whatever you like with `@R=length` before the opening brace of the xymatrix, as in `\xymatrix@R=8ex{ {A} \ar[r]^{\pi}...`.  (You can also set the column spacing with `@C=length` in between the `\xymatrix` and the opening brace.)